# Given a pandas Series that represents frequencies of a value, how can I turn those frequencies into percentages?

Tags: python, pandas

I was experimenting with the kaggle.com Titanic data set (data on every person on the Titanic) and came up with a gender breakdown like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'sex': ['male'] * 577 + ['female'] * 314})
gender = df.sex.value_counts()
gender

male   577
female 314
```

I would like to find out the percentage of each gender on the Titanic.

My approach is slightly less than ideal:

```
from __future__ import division
pcts = gender / gender.sum()
pcts

male      0.647587
female    0.352413
```

Is there a better (more idiomatic) way?

Answer (score 260, accepted):

This function is implemented in pandas, actually even in value_counts(). No need to calculate :)

just type:

```
df.sex.value_counts(normalize=True)
```

which gives exactly the desired output.

Please note that value_counts() excludes NA values, so numbers might not add up to 1.
See here: http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html
(A column of a DataFrame is a Series)

Comment: Any thing which gives as below  

    `male    577 0.647587
    female 314 0.352413`
which can both, counts and pctcnts side by side ??

Answer (score 40):

In case you wish to show percentage one of the things that you might do is use `value_counts(normalize=True)` as [answered by @fanfabbb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24167876/15497888).

With that said, for many purposes, you might want to show it in the percentage out of a hundred.

That can be achieved like so:

```
gender = df.sex.value_counts(normalize=True).mul(100).round(1).astype(str) + '%'
```

In this case, we [multiply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mul.html) the results by hundred, [round](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.round.html) it to one decimal point and add the percentage sign.

Answer (score 32):

If you want to merge counts with percentage, can use:

```
c = df.sex.value_counts(dropna=False)
p = df.sex.value_counts(dropna=False, normalize=True)
pd.concat([c,p], axis=1, keys=['counts', '%'])
```

Comment: there should really be an option to show this automatically!

Answer (score 15):

I think I would probably do this in one go (without importing division):

```
1. * df.sex.value_counts() / len(df.sex)
```

or perhaps, remembering you want a percentage:

```
100. * df.sex.value_counts() / len(df.sex)
```

*Much of a muchness really, your way looks fine too.*

Comment: I like this approach because there's no need to import __future__.  Thanks Hayden.