# Pandas value_counts() with percentage

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook

with the `df['goal'].value_counts()`:

The result is:

```
0   1000
1    500
```

Is there a fast way to also get the `percentage` of with class like:

```
0 1000 66,7%
1  500 33,3%
```

Comment: try this: `df['percentage'] = df.apply(lambda x: x / x.sum(axis=0));df['percentage'] = df['percentage'].map('{:.2%}'.format)`

Comment: [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.value_counts.html) has a normalize parameter. `df['goal'].value_counts(normalize=True)` [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58434981/15497888) in the linked duplicate extends this to include the multiply round and add percentage.